# Yii2 Unable append Ajax success to CKeditor

Tags: ajax, ckeditor, yii2

I was trying to create a newsletter module using Yii2 basic.
This is my scenario,
If a predefined template is available, I have to select that template.
If template is selected the subject and content should be loaded automatically.
For this I am using an Ajax.My Ajax is working perfectly and I appended the newsletter subject with Ajax success,Problem occurred when I tried to append the newsletter content.Hence I am using CKeditor.
**My Form**

```
 <?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use app\modules\admin\models\NewsletterTemplates;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\modules\admin\models\Letter */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="letter-form form_style "  >

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
      <?= $form->field($model, 'letter_template_id')->dropDownList(
         ArrayHelper::map(NewsletterTemplates::find()->all(),'newsletter_temp_id','newsletter_temp_subject'),
        ['prompt' => 'Select','class'=>'form-contol','onchange'=>'
          $.post( "'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('admin/letter/temp?id=').'"+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
            var message = data.split("::");
            //alert(message[1]);
          $( "#letter-letter_sub" ).val( message[0] ); 
          $( "#letter-letter_content" ).val( message[1] ); 

          });'

        ]);
  ?>

    <?php //echo $form->field($model, 'letter_template_id')->textInput(['class'=>'form-contol']) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'letter_to')->textInput(['class'=>'form-contol']) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'letter_sub')->textInput(['class'=>'form-contol']) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'letter_content')->textarea(['class'=>'ckeditor']) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Send' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Can anyone help with this......
Thanks in advance....

Comment: You have to do something like this:
`CKEDITOR.instances[letter-letter_content].insertText(message[1]);`

Comment: Thank you for the hint Muhammed Shahzad

Answer (score 0):

Hi Guys I found out the answer
I just replace the instances of the CKeditor.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'letter_template_id')->dropDownList(
     ArrayHelper::map(NewsletterTemplates::find()->all(),'newsletter_temp_id','newsletter_temp_subject'),
    ['prompt' => 'Select','class'=>'form-contol','onchange'=>'
      $.post( "'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('admin/letter/temp?id=').'"+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
        var message = data.split("::");
      $( "#letter-letter_sub" ).val( message[0] ); 
        CKEDITOR.instances["letter-letter_content"].destroy(true);
        CKEDITOR.replace( "letter-letter_content" );
        var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[ "letter-letter_content" ];
        editor.setData(message[1]);

      });'

    ]);
```

?>
Thank you for your supports